# Настройка стилей CSS

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Всем доброго времени суток!
Подскажите пожалуйста как можно с помощью CSS реализовать следующий порядок блоков (как на скрине)?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

я бы использовал `grid` [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout)

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
.grid > div {
  min-height: 200px;
}
.grid .block {
  grid-column: 1/1;
  grid-row: 1/3;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.grid .label {
  align-item: center;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="block">block1</div>
  <div class="label">label1</div>
  <div class="label">label2</div>
  <div class="label">label3</div>
  <div class="label">label4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @NickGrava если ответили вам верно отметте ответ как верный